# Tagging a ListView item with a JSON string so that it can be used when clicked

Tags: android, json, listview

My aim is to have a list of items retrieved via an api, have them listed on the page and then once clicked on, a new activity is opened where more information is shown.

I currently have the list printed out in a ListView where only the names of (in this case, films) are shown, but would like to tag each ListView item with the complete JSON including all other information such as Age etc so that this can be used as EXTRA information when summoning the new Intent.

My current code for looping through each film in the api is below:

```
  for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String filmTitle = result.getString("Title");
            String filmYear = result.getString("Year");
            String filmDesc = result.getString("Desc");
            String filmPoster = result.getString("Poster");
            Film data = new Film(filmTitle, filmYear, filmDesc, filmPoster);
            ptResults.add(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson library to map JSON String to class u want... Film? Lets say UrClass 
To list add ArrayAdapter with UrClass array and on item select (click) whatever get UrClass object from array and by Gson get again string and can send to other activity in extra field in Intent

Gson has method fromJson toJson

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Film` class implement `Parcelable`.  Then when the user selects an item from the `ListView`, the adapter already has the object to put into the `Intent`.

`Parcelable` classes can be easily written to and read from `Intent`s for transferring entire objects between activities.

`Parcelable` is the Android interface for serialization.  You *could* use `Serializable`, but the `Parcelable` implementation is written for each implementing class so no heavyweight reflection APIs are used.

[Parecelable | Andoid Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)